# If I need to store a lot of related files in the database, should I use MongoDB?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I've begun working on a new project. This project involves keeping track of potentially several thousand documents. Each document is, at a minimum, a row in a table with title, author, description, etc. fields (the primary document table.)

However, each document is or at least can be represented in the file system in several different forms.

For example:

(1) There is or at least should be a pdf version of every document,
(2) If there is a pdf, each page of the pdf is extracted into an image file, and
(3) The text of each document is either extracted from the PDF or derived in some other way.

So every document in the system actually has several (possibly fifty or more, depending on the number of pages) files associated with it.

To be more concise than I was originally:

Each document can have one or many different data objects (pdf files, jpgs, text) associated with it. But the number and type is arbitrary.

Originally, these data objects were just files stored on the server, using a directory structure to keep them organized. Example: /documents/{id}/images, /documents/{id}/pdfs, etc. In order to avoid having to constantly scan the file system, this directory structure was represented in a MySQL database, using lots and lots of tables and foreign keys. Getting all the information about a document -- each and every file associated with it -- required a complicated JOIN.

Would a NoSQL solution like MongoDB be better? I'm especially interested in eventually storing all the files in the database, to better ensure integrity between a document and its data.

Comment: Whether a NoSQL solution is appropriate for a case where you need to store an arbitrary number of potentially largish objects in a database along with some descriptive fields (title, author, whatever.)

Comment: GridFS is exactly designed for this - or?

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I'm asking :-)

Comment: I edited my question to bring it into focus a little more. Sorry I was so verbose.

Comment: Clearly documented in the GridFS docs..

Comment: I've never used GridFS before (or anything other than SQL.) That's why I was asking the question.

If you're saying it will work well for what I've described, then that's what I'll pursue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several thousand and moving to NoSQL?  Let's not underestimate RDBMS like MySQL, Postgres etc.  You can deal with millions of rows without any issues...just make sure your application is properly written.